# Error in calling template function

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I'm getting started with `boost::any` and I'm trying to define a function that given a `boost::any` argument (which initially was a `std::function` object) converts it back to `std::function`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using namespace std;
typedef function<int(int)> intT;

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> converter( boost::any anyFunction) {
    return boost::any_cast<function<ReturnType(Args...)>> (anyFunction);
}

int main()
{
    intT f = [](int i) {return i; };
    boost::any anyFunction = f;
    try
    {
        intT fun = boost::any_cast<intT>(anyFunction);//OK!
        fun = converter(anyFunction);//ERROR!
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_any_cast &)
    {
        cout << "Bad cast" << endl;
    }
}
```

And this is the error returned:

```
1>c:\users\llovagnini\source\repos\cloudcache\cloudcache\cloudcache\memoization.cpp(9): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'anyFunction'
1>  c:\users\llovagnini\source\repos\cloudcache\cloudcache\cloudcache\helloworld.cpp(16): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<int (void)> converter<int,>(boost::any)' being compiled
1>c:\users\llovagnini\source\repos\cloudcache\cloudcache\cloudcache\memoization.cpp(9): error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list
1>c:\users\llovagnini\source\repos\cloudcache\cloudcache\cloudcache\memoization.cpp(9): error C2298: missing call to bound pointer to member function
```

Can you please help me understanding where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**
I solved the parantheses problem, but know the compiler complains because I call `converter` without specifying any type...There is ANY way to keep it generic? It would be REALLY important for my application not to specify `converter<int,int>`

Comment: If you don't want to specify converter<int, int>, then you basically have intT converter(boost::any anyFunction). But then I can't help but wonder what you actually want to do, instead of how...

Comment: Goes for everyone^

Comment: I didn't know that I had to specify at least one type for multiple type templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You... forgot to add parens:

```
return boost::any_cast<std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> >(anyFunction);
```

Next up, you can't deduce the template args, so you have to specify them:

```
fun = converter<int, int>(anyFunction);
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9abbef2ccdfd9492)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

typedef std::function<int(int)> intT;

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> converter(boost::any anyFunction) {
    return boost::any_cast<std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> >(anyFunction);
}

int main()
{
    intT f = [](int i) {return i; };
    boost::any anyFunction = f;
    try
    {
        intT fun = boost::any_cast<intT>(anyFunction); // OK!
        fun = converter<int, int>(anyFunction);        // OK!
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_any_cast &)
    {
        std::cout << "Bad cast" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated at he same time :D

Answer (score 1):

`converter` is a function template, but none of the template parameters are in a deduced context so you have to explicitly provide them:

```
fun = converter<int,int>(anyFunction);
```

Otherwise there's no way to know *which* `converter` to call.